# fgets segmentation fault reading from stdin

Tags: dynamic-memory-allocation, fgets, c-strings

I'm currently trying to read a line from stdin using fgets() but i'm getting a segmentation fault (i'm not geting the segmentation fault anymore, please see edit)

```
int main(void)
{
    char selection;
    string firstName = NULL;

    printf("[A]dd a new client \n");
    printf("[D]isplay all clients \n");
    printf("[I]ncome Average for all clients \n");
    printf("[Q]uit \n");  

    selection = fgetc(stdin);
    printf("\n");

    switch (selection) {
    case 'A':
        printf("First name: ");
        fgets(firstName, MAXNAMESIZE, stdin);
        printf("\n");

        ...
    }
}
```

This is the compiler's output:

```
[A]dd a new client 
[D]isplay all clients 
[I]ncome Average for all clients 
[Q]uit 
A

First name: Segmentation fault
```

Thank you!!

Edit:

i've changed the code like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    char selection;
    string firstName;

    printf("[A]dd a new client \n");
    printf("[D]isplay all clients \n");
    printf("[I]ncome Average for all clients \n");
    printf("[Q]uit \n");  

    selection = fgetc(stdin);
    printf("\n");

    switch (selection) {
        case 'A':
            if ((firstName = malloc(MAXNAMESIZE * sizeof(char))) == NULL)
                return 1;
            printf("First name: ");
            fgets(firstName, MAXNAMESIZE, stdin);
            printf("\n");

        ...
    }
}
```

But now i'm not able to enter any name, the program just ends. This is the output:

```
~/workspace/ $ ./test
[A]dd a new client 
[D]isplay all clients 
[I]ncome Average for all clients 
[Q]uit 
A

First name: 
~/workspace/ $
```

Comment: Whats `string`?

Comment: string is definfed as `char*`

(`typedef char* string`)

Comment: And where does it point to?

Comment: to `NULL`. i tried using `string firstName;` and `string firstName = " ";` but in the first case `firstName` is uninitialized and in the second i also get a segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

You need to `malloc` `firstName` before you can use it, hence make sure to `#include <stdlib.h>`.

Try `string firstName = malloc(MAXNAMESIZE * sizeof(char))`;

Always check that the result of `malloc` is not `NULL`.

Moreover, at the end of your program or when you think it's more useful `free(firstName)` to prevent memory leaks.

Comment: thank you!! now i'm having a different problem... the program wont let me input anything. i've edited the original post with the new code